# How can I rotate object relative to it's local axis?

Tags: transforms

I found a blender 3d model that I would like to use in the game I'm making, however, it's front is at 45' angle relative to it's local axis (see the attached picture). The game engine I'm using (Unity) is using the local axis to determine the front of the object when moving it and as a result the ship "drifts sideways" instead of moving forward.
Is it possible to rotate all the meshes of the ship relative to their local axis?

[image: ship not facing forward]

Comment: Have you applied the objects scale and rotation already? shortcut: CTRL + A

Comment: Can you upload your blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: Thank you @Delagone, CTRL +A -> Apply Rotation did the trick. Additionally I had to rename the object in Unity because it was saving old rotation somewhere (probably meta files). If you will post your comment as answer I'll mark it as accepted.


The original blend can be found here: http://opengameart.org/content/ship   (The axis there are already like this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the rotation will solve this issue.

Shortcut: **CTRL + A**

This will make the rotation to be equivalent to 0 degrees in each plane.
The selection will not be rotated, the current rotation will be considered to be the default rotation.

[image]